# Is a FIND_NODE ethereum packet encrypted

Tags: go-ethereum, security

I was trying to inspect ethereum discovery protocol packets on my local machine using a private blockchain created using geth. I captured the packets using a tcpdump, and imported the pcap file into wireshark(I added the ConsesSys plugin for ethereum packets in wireshark). Post this, I was able to clearly see the packets being exchanged. However, 1 thing that confused me was that they didn’t seem encrypted. For example, I was running 2 miners on the private blockchain on separate nodes. Hence, I could see PING, PONG, NODES and FIND_NODES messages being passed. In the NODES packet, however, I could easily inspect the packet and see the neighbor list with the IP and port visible. Does this mean the packet is not encrypted? If it does mean that, does that affect security of the ethereum network?

If no, why is that?

If yes, how? And are there any work in progress tasks aiming to solve this?

I’m a complete beginner, so sorry if the question seems off.